# Best practice to to access components using scripts in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity so go easy on me. :)

I added an game object with a text field component (via `TextMeshProUGUI`) to my heads up display in my scene. I want to use this to display various statistics on it for debugging purposes during game play.

I then created a script which I added as a component to the same game object that holds my text component. Is this the best practice? Not sure how else I would get the script to execute.

Once I had my script created, I needed to find the text component as well as some other components in my scene so I could display the debug information. Below you can see how I did it... it feels a little dirty to be searching the entire scene to find these things. Would love some insight on how long-time Unity programmers go about this!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerDebugStatistics:MonoBehaviour {
    TextMeshProUGUI playerDebugStatisticsText;
    PlayerCharacterController playerCharacterController;
    Health playerHealth;

    private void Start() {
        // First find the object in the scene named "PlayerDebugStatisticsText" and then get it's TextMeshProUGUI component
        this.playerDebugStatisticsText = GameObject.Find("PlayerDebugStatisticsText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

        // Get the player character controller
        this.playerCharacterController = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerCharacterController>();

        // Get the player health from the player character controller
        this.playerHealth = playerCharacterController.GetComponent<Health>();
    }

    void Update() {
        // Update the text every frame
        this.playerDebugStatisticsText.SetText(string.Format("{0:N2}", this.playerHealth.currentHealth));
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question but more a code review or a post in the software engineering forum i dont feel like this belongs on stackoverflow. Also i find that with these questions the unity q/a or forums tend to get more response

Comment: An efficient way would be not to use find method at all but rather to reference objects in your script.

Answer (score 1):

**3 ways**

1. **Create an inspector reference** to the other object and access it from your script - a public or private (with [SerializeField]) attribute in your script - and drag the component in like in this video: https://youtu.be/dMgQOP7kdxg?t=425
2. **Use the singleton pattern:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5p2JlI7PV1w
3. **Use dependency injection** - https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject

Your way isn't terrible if you don't do it in the Update() loop, and cache your objects (like it appears you are doing), but if you need that performance in Start(), the above options can help.